# having issues applying flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, google-developer-tools

I'm having some issues applying flexbox on a div.

here is the problem :

```
<div class="annual-plan">
        <div class="icon">
          <i class="fas fa-music"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="pricing">
          <h3>Annual Plan</h3>
          <span>$59.99/year</span>
        </div>
        <a href="#">Change</a>
 </div>
```

this whole code is wrapped in div with a class named content-section

i tried targeting it with css using the following :

```
.content-section .annual-plan .pricing{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

but still doesn't take effect, and you can see no space between.
[image]

I checked the dev tools of chrome and it's not overridden by any other code.

what did I do wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the default `padding` on `h3` and nest your code in a `container` then apply flex-boxes to each, and use `justify-content: space-between;` to space your elements.

```css
.annual-plan {
    background-color: lightgrey;
    border-radius: 30px;
    width: 400px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 30px;
}

h3 {
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
 }
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<div class="container">
<div class="annual-plan">
        <div class="icon">
          <i class="fas fa-music">Logo</i>
        </div>
        <div class="pricing">
          <h3>Annual Plan</h3>
          <span>$59.99/year</span>
        </div>
        <a href="#">Change</a>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here, as you've described it, is just that you've got the wrong selector. You've explicitly targeted that central `.pricing` div, but it reads to me like you want the whole `.annual-plan` to render as a column... If so, you should try just deleting `.pricing` from the selector in your above code.

Here that is, with some extra colors and all that.

```css
.annual-plan {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  /* extra styles just for fun */
  background: lightgrey;
  border-radius: 12px;
  padding: 1em;
  min-height: 12em;
  max-width: 33.3333%;
}

.annual-plan .pricing {
  text-align: center;
}

/* more styles just for fun */
h3 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="annual-plan">
  <div class="icon">
    <i class="fas fa-music"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="pricing">
    <h3>Annual Plan</h3>
    <span>$59.99/year</span>
  </div>
  <a href="#">Change</a>
</div>
```